# Hiding a single div section of a website with no selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a single snippet of code on my website as I upgraded to beta software and can't revert back without playing with my database.

I have attempted to use JQuery which I have achieved before though this div has no selector.

I am a graphic designer though have a small knowledge of code.

I also don't know how to find where the snippet has been input either nor can I just change the CSS. You can see it as the beta license warning in the yellow box.

Any help will be appreciated, the website is (Removed to prevent abuse)

Comment: What do you mean by "no selector"? There are no elements "without selector". Give this element an ID and hide it using either jQuery or vanilla JS.

Comment: how can you hide if you wont select?

Comment: I am assuming it is input from php, I cannot find the input so I either need to know where to track it back to in the files or a way to find out what the selector is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this use case is actually legitimate and you have a valid license, you could just select child elements, for example to remove the beta warning:

```
$('#main-body div div div:first-child').css('display', 'none')
```

This selects the first child within several nested `div` elements, and hides it using the style `display:none;`

Comment: Apologies, this does look dodgey!! Here is proof I have a paid and a beta license http://i66.tinypic.com/dwoo0m.png

Comment: @TimSalabim: No problem, had to include the disclaimer just in case :-)

Comment: Of course. That was taking me so long to work out!! Thank you. Should I be removing this in case of abuse?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('main-body').children[0].children[0].children[0].style.display = 'none';
```

When the above code is called the div will be hidden.

It basically gets the position of an element with a selector, and then goes from child to child and then finally hides the snippet of code.

Hope this helps.